# View Controller changes its height to the height of a Scroll View

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a Scroll View with a button in it. Then I have another View Controller. I Ctrl dragged from this button to that second VC to preform a segue. Button and VC are connected, however, VC’s height is same as Scroll view’s one

I tried to choose that second VC and in attribute inspector I changed its height and it seems it was changed, however, in Storyboard, VC is as long as the Scroll View

Do you know how to fix this?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbuF6.jpg) you can see what it looks like

PS: Sorry for not so clear title, I just had no idea how to explain it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to specify the second view controller's size by selecting it and choosing Simulated Size: Freeform option.

[image: Freeform]

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. I don't know why I didn't try it. Anyway, do you know this happened?

Comment: I don't know why it looked like that by default, to be honest I avoid storyboards with more than one view controller :)